# How to limit the amount of Windows updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, notification-area

I'm working with a Windows-10 environment, and I have the habit to install updates directly after I get the notification.

However, this is getting really annoying: I just had the situation where I got notified about an update, I download and install it, and in not more than one minute afterwards I get a new notification.

Is is possible to configure my PC in such a way only to show one or two notifications during the whole day?

Comment: Just schedule the update the day after security updates are released (after patch Tuesday)

Comment: And which scheduled task is that? There seem to be some many and the most I looked at seem to have acceptable triggers.

Comment: You set the activity hours/schedule an installation time within the Windows Update settings (same as always)

Comment: activate "quiet hours" to get rid of the toast notifications: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/bbc7244e-219f-7454-4641-269a6ff35cbe/turn-quiet-hours-on-in-windows-10.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the version that came out in March/April "The Creator's Update" (v1703) you will see that there is now a whole host of options to delay updates, and when to question you about them. You will likely also find better times to schedule the updates so that you are less-likely to be interrupted during active hours.